# NCURSES обрабатывает потерю фокуса терминала и выводит символы ML

Tags: c++, ncurses

Возникла проблема. По гайдам в интернете написал свой консольный текстовый редактор на с++ используя ncurses. Решил добавить туда обработку нажатия мыши `mousemask(ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS, NULL)`, но приложение отлавливает нажатия не только на саму область консоли, но и потерю фокуса самим окном приложения(консоли) и его восстановление и начинает писать в консоль MLMLMLMLM. Не могу понять, как это отловить. Как `KEY_MOUSE` не получается, все равно выводится, задать маску только нажатия на какую-либо кнопку по типу `mousemask(BUTTON1_CLICKED, NULL)` не получается. Нужна ваша помощь. Вот ссылка на [GitHub](https://github.com/VtripleG/TEG.git), вдруг будет нужно